# Добавление значения роста в матричной визуализации в Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Как в матричной визуализации добавить столбец роста значений.
Например есть данные по продажам по региону и данные по годам. Хочу также в этой же визуализации подставить величину отношения год к году.
На картинке снизу представлен пример. Хочу добавить столбец с отношением 2018/2017.

[image: Пример]

И сразу же еще вопрос, как сделать сортировку не по "Всего" а по определенному году.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать создав отдельные 2 меры на 2017 и 2018 год и третью с их отношением.
Примерно так.

```
2017 = SUMX(
    FILTER(
            'mt';
            'mt'[year] = "2017"
            );
            'mt'[cost])
2018 = SUMX(
    FILTER(
            'mt';
            'mt'[year] = "2018"
            );
            'mt'[cost])
2018/2017(%) = IFERROR((([2018] / [2017] - 1)*100); 0)
```